# Simplest way to deal with long text strings in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to loop over files line by line and replace specific strings in them, but I'm running in to a problem where some lines are very long and do not get assigned to a variable. I'm at a loss how to fix this.

This is the script I have now:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set VAR=%~1

set INTEXTFILE=%VAR%
set OUTTEXTFILE=Adapted/%VAR%

for /f "tokens=* delims=¶" %%A in (%INTEXTFILE%) do (
    SET "modified=%%A"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET modified=!modified:Field_Name=Other_Field_Name!
    echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

I want to add something that would let this script also handle very long text strings but I am not experienced in batch scripts at all and cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: Strings in batch have an effective limit of 2047 characters. If this isn't enough, you may want to consider redoing this with something more suited to text manipulation - the UNIX/Linux utilities `sed` and `awk` immediately come to mind; there are [Windows ports for them](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). If you can't or don't want to install additional software, you might also consider PowerShell, which is built-in to Windows 7 and later.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin If I don't get it wrongly, the strings should have a limit of 8191, not 2047. And if you call `sed`/`awk` directly from the batch-file with a variable as parameter, then the variable expansion may make a line longer then 8191 character, giving incorrect parameter to `sed`/`awk`.

Comment: The point is that if you're using `sed` or `awk` correctly, you won't end up passing variables that will need to be expanded - you process the file directly with one of those; you don't have batch read the contents of the file into a variable and then pass that to it.